# Как создать переменную в Laravel в классе чтоб она была видна внутри функций этого класса?

Tags: php, laravel

Имеется код в контроллере Laravel, которая использует функции хелпера, в котором используется фасад **Request**:

```
public static $regions, $current_region;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $regions = RegionInfo::get_region($request)[0];
        $current_region = RegionInfo::get_region($request)[1];
    }
```

Однако, она выдаёт ошибку
**Undefined variable $request**.

В общем, как создать переменные **$regions, $current_region** так, чтобы они были видны другим функциям контроллера?

Comment: все верно, переменной $request в функции нет... Ошибка явно вам это говорит. Да и зачем в конструкторе контроллера вы это делаете не понятно)

Comment: Потому что эти переменные используются в контроллере

Comment: @Салават скажите, у вас не возникло после предыдущего комментария мысли о том, что это нужно делать не в конструкторе контроллера, а в конструкторе какого-то другого класса?

Comment: @boneskhv, предлагаете создать отдельный класс, в котором хранятся эти переменные и уже контроллер расширить этим классом?

Comment: Ни в коем случае, просто уточнил, что вы все верно поняли

Answer (score 2):

Для доступа к статическим переменным внутри класса используйте ключевое слово **self**

```
self::$regions = RegionInfo::get_region($request)[0];
self::$current_region = RegionInfo::get_region($request)[1];
```

Но у вас проблема в том, что класс не знает что такое $request, о чем явно говорит ошибка. **Откуда у вас берется $request ?**

Во-вторых, точно ли нужны вам статические значения свойств класса? Если вы их динамически меняете при каждом создании экземпляра класса, то лучше их сделать динамическими. Например так:

```
public $region; 
public $current_region;

public fucntion __construct(Requets $request)
{
    $this->region = RegionInfo::get_region($request)[0];
    $this->current_region = RegionInfo::get_region($request)[1];
}
```

Не экономьте стрчоки в коде. Используйте статику только там, где она действительно нужна.